# How to determine when Queue is complete on LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-metadata, queue, callback

I'm currently trying to create a tool that creates a metadata record in LWC. I'm using `Metadata.Operators.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, new DeployCallback())` to create a new record, and it's able to create properly. What I'm stuck on is how I can update this record in my LWC when the queue to create/update the record is done.

The hacky method that I currently have is to have a timeout on the frontend to retrieve the data after a certain amount of time (after saving), but I'm assuming there should be a better way to do this that doesn't rely on something like this.

Comment: Not 100% sure but check out Apex continuations that might be helpful here. [Continuation Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-continuations-component-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a Message Channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-message-channel-intro.html), then in LWC, use the [lightning-message-service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) to listen for that channel event, and finally, in your `DeployCallback`, you can use [`EventBus.publish`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_eventbus.htm) to notify the LWC that the operation is complete. You can use the ID you get from `Metadata.operations.enqueueDeployment` to make sure the LWC gets the record it expects. I'd recommend not subscribing until just before you make the initial call, and unsubscribe immediately afterwards, to avoid hitting the [Platform Event Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm).